# How can I pass parameters to on_key in fig.canvas.mpl_connect('key_press_event', on_key)?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a function

```
def on_key(event):
```

Which I call from

```
fig.canvas.mpl_connect('key_press_event', on_key)
```

I would like to pass the parameters plt1, plt2, plt3 to on_key...

how can I do this?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Probably

```
def on_key(event, arg1, arg2, arg3):
```

and

```
fig.canvas.mpl_connect('key_press_event', lambda event: on_key(event, plt1, plt2, plt3))
```

or as list

```
def on_key(event, args_list):
```

and

```
fig.canvas.mpl_connect('key_press_event', lambda event: on_key(event, [plt1, plt2, plt3]))
```